# jquery - form data not being passed in ajax call

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I've used this exact code before - with PHP as the processing page but now in coldfusion (regardless if I uses a cfc or just a cfm to process) the jQuery doesn't seem to pass the form object - 
well... if I look at the firebug response, the 'post' tab DOES show all the field and their values.. application/x-www-form-urlencoded HOWEVER the page responsible in the URL attribute doesn't get it.. and (in the example delow) the console log( data ) shows an empty string.

Heres what I have....

```
$( '#create_client' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

    //form validation
    var bValid = true;

    if ( bValid ) {
        // AJAX Post data
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            url: '/cfc/clent.cfc?method=put',
            data: $( '#client-form' ).serialize(),
            success: function( data ){
                console.log(data);
                loadClientTable();
            },
            error: function(){
                // tell user there was a problem
                $( '#clients-message' ).html( '<p>There was a problem submitting your request... Doh!</p>' );
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and here's the form

```
<form name="client-form" id="client-form" class="singleLineForm" >
<label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" maxlength="15" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" maxlength="15" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" maxlength="50" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="password">Password: </label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" maxlength="20" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="isActive">Active? </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="isActive" id="isActive" value="1" class="checkbox ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<input type="button" name="create_client" id="create_client" value="Create Client" class="button ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</form>
```

the put in the cfc looks like this (for now)

```
<cffunction name="put" access="public" returntype="structure" hint="PUT method, handles data transfering." >
    <cfargument name="email" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="password" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="firstname" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="lastname" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="isActive" type="numeric" required="yes" >

    <cfset _return = '' />

    <cfquery name="insertClient" datasource="#application.DSNwrite#" >
        INSERT INTO clients
        ( 
            email
            ,password
            ,firstname
            ,lastname
            ,isActive
        )
        VALUES
        ( 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim( arguments.email )#" />
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim( arguments.password )#" />
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim( arguments.firstname )#" />
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim( arguments.lastname )#" />
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#val( arguments.isActive )#" />
        )
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn _return />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in client.put()?

Comment: @scott - there ya go...

Comment: maybe try changing POST to PUT?

Comment: Checking the database table for the new record would be a more accurate test of your assumption. You could return "Yay, it worked" but that only means it got to the end without an error. It doesn't mean it did what you expected. If you're values weren't passed you would have gotten an error at `<CFARGUMENT>` because the values are required.

Answer (score 5):

Your CFC method is returning an empty string.

You have this:

```
<cfset _return = '' />
```

and at the end of the method, you have this:

```
<cfreturn _return />
```

Yet, you never set `_return` to a different value. To test is this is the problem, try this:

```
 <cfset _return = 'moo' />
```

If you get 'moo' returned, everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below to pass form data in `ajax` call.

```
var formData = $('#client-form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/cfc/clent.cfc?method=put&' + formData,
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
    },
    success: function(data){},
    error: function(data){},
})
```